# Output Raw String in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a site built with ASP.NET MVC. I have a string in my view model that looks like this:

```
ViewBag.Text = "{\"1\":{\"1\":\"John\",\"2\":\"Bill\",\"3\":\"Paul\"},\"3\":{}}";
```

I want to output this into my view like this:

```
<input id='myHiddenInput' type='hidden' value='@ViewBag.Text' />
```

When the view gets rendered, the hidden element looks like this:

```
<input id='myHiddenInput' type='hidden' value='{&quot;1&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;John&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Bill&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;Paul&quot;},&quot;3&quot;:{}}' />
```

How do I update the view so that the output looks like the following:

```
<input id='myHiddenInput' type='hidden' value='{"1":{"1":"John";,"2":"Bill","3":"Paul"},"3":{}}' />
```

I know this seems goofy. This really is what i need to do though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) to output the unencoded data:

```
<input id='myHiddenInput' type='hidden' value='@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Text)' />
```

Here is a link to [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivsJWx). You can see the output in text field, but there is also a hidden field with the same unencoded information.

Comment: Oddly, that is not working for me. I do not know why. Any ideas?

Comment: @xamdeveloper I updated answer with working edition on dotnetfiddle. It is hard to tell why it is not working in your case without seeing the full code. Maybe looking at fiddle will help you resolve the issues

Comment: @dotnetom, thank you so much for introducing me to dotnetfiddle! Had no idea it existed for mvc! :)