# How to render and preserve <br> tags as line breaks using @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm migrating an ASP Classic app to ASP.Net MVC 5. The legacy data contains `<BR>` tags in the text. In the old application (still in use) the tags are rendered as line breaks. The data was created and displayed using plain html `<textarea>` tags. A list of Mill Roll numbers, for example, is entered in a single field on multiple lines. How can I preserve this behavior in MVC? I've tried:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MillRoll, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The result is an input control displaying a single line of multiple Mill Rolls with the `<BR>` tag between each roll number instead of displaying multiple lines. I'm not interested in breaking the data off into another table. The new app will need to behave like the old allowing entry and saving of multiple lines in a single input control. I'd like to make the transition to the MVC app simple for both myself and users.

Comment: what does the old app do? Does it convert the BRs to newlines just before it adds it to the textarea? And back again when it submits? You might have to do the same. Or if the data to be input is actually a list, consider using multiple input fields. Probably more user-friendly. If it still needs to be stored in one DB field (yuk) then you can always combine them when the form is posted back. You said "I'm not interested in breaking the data off into another table" - why not? A rewrite is an ideal opportunity to normalise the data. Much easier for reporting etc.

Comment: The old app doesn't appear to convert anything. I think the output of the plain <textarea> contains <br> which is saved to the database. I'm not actually in a development environment for the old app, just looking at the page code.

Comment: I'm not breaking the data into another table because I'm not sure of the workflow for myself in switching off the old application and turning on the new without losing data.

Comment: well to switch off and on with a new data structure you'd need a migration script to convert between one structure and the other. Breaking a field up into lots of fields where there's a clear delimiter (the br) shouldn't be very difficult. It's a well understood problem. And then this display issue, and all sorts of data/reporting problems instantly vanish

Comment: After reading your first comment I see it is converting the data. Not sure why. This is what I found: MillRoll = Replace(Request.Form("MillRoll"),vbCRLF,"<BR>")

Comment: It's converting the data because otherwise it'll display BRs as text - a textarea won't allow markup injection into it. Whereas it _will_ allow newline characters. You will find something is converting them back to <br>s again before saving to the DB.

Comment: Now I also see: frmOnHold.MillRoll.Value = Replace("<%=(MillRoll)%>","<BR>",vbCRLF)

Comment: you'll have to do the same then, when you populate your model, and when you save it. But...I would strongly advise you to grab the bull by the horns and sort out the data structure. Because it's hideous and breaks the most fundamental rules of relational data.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you use to display the output?  You could try `Html.Raw` - eg if you were using `@model.message` to display your database text  try `@Html.Raw(model.Message)` instead. Your classic asp code makes things more complicated than they need to be.  The obvious place to convert `vbcrlf` to `<br>` is when the data is retrieved from the database, not when it's inserted.  Also, I don't know if you're familiar with the css property `white-space:pre-line` which all current browsers support.  It saves you from having to replace your line breaks server side.

Comment: How would I use @Html.Raw or css to allow both display WITHOUT <BR> and input saved WITH <BR>?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert data on the fly using properties for example.
Replace "< br >" with "\r\n" and back (You can also use System.Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n"). 

So when you get legacy data, replace "< br > with "\r\n" it should then show ok it textarea. If you need to save changes in legacy format with < br >  just replace "\r\n" with < br > and save it.

```
public string myLegacyDataString;
public string MyDataString{
    get {return myLegacyDataString.Replace("< br >","\r\n");}
    set {myLegacyDataString = value.Replace("\r\n", "< br >");}
}
```

or with NewLine:

```
public string myLegacyDataString;
public string MyDataString{
    get {return myLegacyDataString.Replace("< br >",System.Environment.NewLine);}
    set {myLegacyDataString = value.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "< br >");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.Raw to preserve the BR tags

```
@Html.Raw("<br>")
```

The idea came from here:  [Output Raw String in ASP.NET MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844388/output-raw-string-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)

I've been working on a project that involves re-writing old vbscript asp.net code as well.  The old code would often put BR tags into strings to display on the page.  But razor would dutifully display it as `&lt;br&gt;`.  So it would show up on my page as a `<BR>` instead of a line break.

I don't have access to your code (you probably have moved on from trying to solve this, by now) but I imagine if you put something like:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => @Html.Raw(model.MillRoll), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

it would give you what you want.

(You many need to not include the @ symbol by Html.Raw.  I can never seem to understand exactly when it is needed with Razor.)